# Custom Auth request in ServiceStack for multi-tenancy

Tags: authentication, servicestack

I am already using a custom authentication provider in my ServiceStack based web services application.

I'm overriding the Authenticate method, and validating my user against one of multiple backend tenant databases. I currently determine the tenant database by matching an API key to a database string.

```
public override object Authenticate(
   IServiceBase authService, 
   IAuthSession session, 
   Auth request) // <- custom object here, MyCustomAuth request
{
   // ...
}
```

This works when each application is for a single tenant (a tenant/customer can build their own application and use that API key). Moving forward I want to build a multi-tenant mobile application. Thus the API key method cannot be used because I can't expect each user to type it in, hence I can't determine which tenant is using the application.

I wanted to alter the Auth object so that I could include the TenantId (provided by the user on login). However, I can't see how I can customize that object.

Is there anyway to customize that Auth object, or do I have to find an alternative solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't modify the built-in `Authenticate` Request DTO used, but you can use its `Dictionary<string, string> Meta` property to send additional metadata with the Authenticate request, e.g:

```
client.Post(new Authenticate {
    ...
    Meta = new Dictionary<string,string> {
        {"TenantId", tenantId},
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can send additional info in the QueryString or HTTP Headers and access the `IRequest` with:

```
var tenantId = authService.Request.QueryString["TenantId"];
```

Comment: Is the `Meta` property post v3.9.x? Also, for the same 3.9.x version (.48) I assume I need to do `authService.RequestContext.Get<IHttpRequest>().Items["TenantId"]` ?

Comment: @Junto Authenticate.Meta was added in v4. That's how to access the current Request in v3 but you'd still want to look at the QueryString if that's what you're looking for.